# php create json multiple arrays

Tags: php, json, wordpress

php create json multiple arrays. Following code with php i need output like that json .. so many array and object confusing me. we using wordpres

```
<?php 
 $categories = get_categories( array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent'  => 0
  ));

 foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $category_id =  $category->term_id;
    $category_name = $category->name;
    echo  $category_name;
    echo "<br>";

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category'  => $category_id
        );

        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){
            $category_postname = $post->post_title;
            echo $category_postname;
            echo "<br>";
        }
}
?>
```

Php output is"

```
    Testcat1
      pos1
      post2
    Testcat2
      post3
      post4
    TestCat3
      post5
      post 6
```

I need create Json  like this:

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "cat": "Testcat1",
          "post": [
            {
              "name": "post1"
            },
            {
              "name": "post2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "cat": "Testcat2",
          "post": [
            {
              "name": "post3"
            },
            {
              "name": "post4"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "cat": "Testcat3",
          "post": [
            {
              "name": "post5"
            },
            {
              "name": "post6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i need like this json output.

Comment: what about json_encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put everything in an array and the json_encode it. I commented out your echos, so you could use them if you need later.

```
<?php 
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent'  => 0
));

// init empty array with root "data"
$array = array( 'data' => array() );
// set counter to 0 for array later on
$n = 0;

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $category_id =  $category->term_id;
    $category_name = $category->name;

    // store cat.name
    $array['data'][$n]['cat'] = $category_name;
    // echo  $category_name;
    // echo "<br>";

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category'  => $category_id
    );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    // init posts counter
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $myposts as $post ){
        $category_postname = $post->post_title;
        $array['data'][$n]['post'][$i]['name'] = $category_postname;
        $array['data'][$n]['post'][$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
        // echo $category_postname;
        // echo "<br>";
        // increment post loop counter
        $i++;
    }

    // increment counter for array
    $n++;
}

echo json_encode( $array );
?>
```

Comment: @suresh no problem: you can choose this answer as being the one you will use, by the way

Comment: how can i add $category_postid inside post array?? "post": [
            {
              "name": "post5","id": "1",
           }

Comment: You will need an extra counter in the $myposts loop. I will edit the code